# php unwritable with 755 permisions

Tags: php, joomla, chmod

I finished installed my joomla 3 en my server debian and this show in the php configurations php unwritable so I pressed the next button and after I went to my server so as root change the permission to my site to 755 but the message in the System information -> Directory permission show me unwritable again, like show below.

```
Directory    Status

administrator/components    Unwritable
administrator/language  Unwritable
administrator/language/overrides    Unwritable
administrator/language/en-GB    Unwritable
administrator/manifests/files   Unwritable
administrator/manifests/libraries   Unwritable
administrator/manifests/packages    Unwritable
administrator/modules   Unwritable
administrator/templates Unwritable
components  Unwritable
images  Unwritable
images/headers  Unwritable
images/sampledata   Unwritable
images/banners  Unwritable
language    Unwritable
language/overrides  Unwritable
language/en-GB  Unwritable
libraries   Unwritable
media   Unwritable
modules Unwritable
plugins Unwritable
plugins/authentication  Unwritable
plugins/content Unwritable
plugins/editors-xtd Unwritable
plugins/system  Unwritable
plugins/search  Unwritable
plugins/quickicon   Unwritable
plugins/captcha Unwritable
plugins/finder  Unwritable
plugins/extension   Unwritable
plugins/user    Unwritable
plugins/editors Unwritable
plugins/twofactorauth   Unwritable
templates   Unwritable
configuration.php   Unwritable
cache (Cache Directory) Unwritable
administrator/cache (Cache Directory)   Unwritable
/var/www/magoprat/logs (Log directory)  Unwritable
/var/www/magoprat/tmp (Temp directory)  Unwritable
```

anyone know what happens? thanks in advance

Comment: `755` means RWX for owner, RX for group, and RX for all. Your Apache probably runs under the group, not the owner.

Comment: Do the write permissions specified for the directory match up with the proper user/group under which your server is running?

Comment: Have you tried to change the owner of the files to be the same as you apache server?

Comment: Andrew made a good point try 777 temporarily to see if it works. If so, try 775 or change ownership.

Comment: yes, I do that and work but obviusly I don't want to change the permission each time which wanted install a plugins or template.

Comment: now I have a question, what user ran my apache when a request is sent from a web browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, I do this, I changed the group but I kept the user as root with the script which show      below:

```
chown -R root:www-data folder-to-changed/
```

and after changed the permission thus.

```
chmod -R 775 folder-to-changed/
```

according to what I've read, these files need be of root user and the group of apache user

I hope this were correct.